# Having difficulty installing pygames to python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm still a novice to all the advanced parts of coding. i have the 3.9.11 version of python installed. Whenever i install Pygames, I always get this result below. Any way that i could resolve this? thanks!

```
C:\\Users\\username\>pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev14
Collecting pygame==2.0.0.dev14
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/f6/9031970fbd0cabb02842a68b6bd2defc55f4c1409e76712dd32c4d6e46cf/pygame-2.0.0.dev14.tar.gz (5.6MB)
100% |################################| 5.6MB 74kB/s
c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages_distutils_hack\__init_\_.py:18: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools, but importing Setuptools also replaces the `distutils` module in `sys.modules`. This may lead to undesirable behaviors or errors. To avoid these issues, avoid using distutils directly, ensure that setuptools is installed in the traditional way (e.g. not an editable install), and/or make sure that setuptools is always imported before distutils.
"Distutils was imported before Setuptools, but importing Setuptools "
c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages_distutils_hack\__init_\_.py:30: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\commands\\install.py", line 294, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\req\\req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
functools.partial(self.\_prepare_file, finder))
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\req\\req_set.py", line 321, in \_walk_req_to_install
more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\req\\req_set.py", line 505, in _prepare_file_
abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\req\\req_set.py", line 123, in prep_for_dist
self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\req\\req_install.py", line 376, in run_egg_info
self.setup_py, self.name,
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\req\\req_install.py", line 347, in setup_py
import setuptools  # noqa
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\__init_.py", line 8, in \<module\>
import _distutils_hack.override  # noqa: F401_
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages_distutils_hack\\override.py", line 1, in \<module\>
__import__('_distutils_hack').do_override()_
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages_distutils_hack\__init_.py", line 72, in do_override
ensure_local_distutils()
File "c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages_distutils_hack\__init_.py", line 59, in ensure_local_distutils
assert '\_distutils' in core.__file__, core.__file__
AssertionError: c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\distutils\\core.py
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Have you tried *upgrading via the `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` command*? Your pip version is outdated.

Comment: I was able to install it. thank you!

Comment: @KwabenaBadu it looks to me that the python version used is not 3.9, but 3.5

Answer (score 1):

First things first, upgrade your pip putting this in your cmd: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Why are you installing lower version of pygame? Also if you don't have a specific reason to use python 3.9, you can install python 3.10. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling python so it reinstalls the pip and then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I tried that before, but i get "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe: No module named pip" as the result.

Comment: I have this as the result:

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe: No module named pip

Comment: Reinstalled python then, so you will automatically reinstall pip

Comment: I was able to install it. thank you!